# typedef enum of notes, making static array that maps frequency to note

Tags: c, enums, typedef

I have an enumeration for each of the notes I want defined below:

```
typedef enum
{
    NOTE_C0 = 0,
    NOTE_CS0,
    NOTE_D0,
    NOTE_DS0,
    NOTE_E0,
    NOTE_F0,
    NOTE_FS0,
    NOTE_G0,
    NOTE_GS0,
    NOTE_A0,
    NOTE_AS0,
    NOTE_B0,

    NOTE_C1,
    NOTE_CS1,
    NOTE_D1,
    NOTE_DS1,
    NOTE_E1,
    NOTE_F1,
    NOTE_FS1,
    NOTE_G1,
    NOTE_GS1,
    NOTE_A1,
    NOTE_AS1,
    NOTE_B1,

    NUM_NOTES
} note_t;
```

I want to create a static array that maps the frequency values to the note.

This is for a programming assignment, and for some reason I'm blanking on how to do that.

```
static note_t noteList = {261.63,277.18, ...}; ?
```

Would it be something like that?

Comment: Note to frequency is easy (just array index), but you can't use floats as array indices. You'll have to do a search of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of your suggestion can be made to work, as long as you're careful, in any version of C:

```
static double noteList[] = { 261.63, 277.18, … };
```

You need to position the frequencies at the right index based on the enumeration.  Later on, you can use

```
printf("%.2f\n", noteList[NOTE_G0]);
```

to print the frequency corresponding to the G natural above middle C.

If C99 or later is an option, consider using designated initializers instead:

```
static double frequencies[] =
{
    [NOTE_C0] = 261.63,
    [NOTE_CS0] = 277.18,
    [NOTE_D0] = …,
    [NOTE_DS0] = …,
    …
};
```

I've renamed the array more nearly appropriately; the notation you'll use is the array notation. This works even if there are gaps in the list of initializers; you'd spot them because some indexes would have a zero frequency where you expected some non-zero frequency.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jonathan Leffler's answer. You can't use floating-point numbers as array indices, so you can't use arrays to easily map frequencies to notes. You can however use this equivalency:

```
frequency = 440 * 2^(note / 12)
```

(where `note = 0` corresponds to A over middle C), by transforming it to:

```
note = 12 * log2(frequency / 400)
```

which, translated to C becomes:

```
int note = round(12.0 * log2(frequency / 440.0));
```

Be aware that here `note = 0` corresponds to A over middle C, so add 9 to get it to map to your frequency-array.